# getfileinfo not working in Joseph Wright's model dtx file creating a class

Tags: dtx

I love Joseph Wright's model dtx file for style file creation, but would like to use it for classes, too. So I did some replacements in it (`sty` -> `cls` and the like) and got this `democls.dtx`:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% !TEX program  = pdfLaTeX
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*readme>
----------------------------------------------------------------
democls --- description text
E-mail: you@your.domain
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------

Some text about the class: probably the same as the abstract.
%</readme>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
----------------------------------------------------------------
democls --- description text
E-mail: you@your.domain
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------

\endpreamble
\postamble

Copyright (C) 2009 by You <you@your.domain>

This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
version.  The latest version of this license is in the file:

http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt

This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by
You.

This work consists of the file  democls.dtx
and the derived files           democls.ins,
                                democls.pdf and
                                democls.cls.

\endpostamble

\usedir{tex/latex/democls}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.cls}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{class}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/democls}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{doc/latex/democls}
\generate{
  \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*class>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{democls}[2009/10/06 v1.0 description text]
%</class>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[numbered]{hypdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
%\GetFileInfo{\jobname.cls}
%
%\title{^^A
%  \textsf{democls} --- description text\thanks{^^A
%    This file describes version \fileversion, last revised \filedate.^^A
%  }^^A
%}
%\author{^^A
%  You\thanks{E-mail: you@your.domain}^^A
%}
%\date{Released \filedate}
%
%\maketitle
%
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{First public release}
%
%\DescribeMacro{\examplemacro}
% Some text about an example macro called \cs{examplemacro}, which

% might have an optional argument \oarg{arg1} and mandatory one
% \marg{arg2}.
%
%\StopEventually{^^A
%  \PrintChanges
%  \PrintIndex
%}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*class>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%\begin{macro}{\examplemacro}
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{Some change from the previous version}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*\examplemacro[2][]{%
  Some code here, probably
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</class>
%    \end{macrocode}
%\Finale
```

However, compiling the `dtx` file shows that `\filedate` and `\fileversion`, generated by `\GetFileInfo` got wrong values:

[image]

There has been a comment by @MartinScharrer to a related question saying:

However, I guess the cause of trouble is the `\ProvidesClass` line before the `\documentclass`. It should be there, at least not in this form, because it is taken as part of the driver document. There are some `\iffalse .. \fi` missing or use `%<class>\ProvidesClass` instead.

I have been moving around stuff in my `democls.dtx` to no avail. How can I get this working?

Comment: The model probably needs a few tweaks: I'd (now) move the `\ProvidesPackage` line to the start of the documented code part. Perhaps I should do a new blog post on this!

Answer (score 7):

You can only use `\GetFileInfo` for code you've loaded as part of the LaTeX run, which limits the use here to packages (unless you are writing a class for code documentation). Thus you have to input the information in an alternative way. The easiest is simply to define `\fileversion` and `\filedate`

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*readme>
----------------------------------------------------------------
democls --- description text
E-mail: you@your.domain
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------

Some text about the class: probably the same as the abstract.
%</readme>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble
----------------------------------------------------------------
democls --- description text
E-mail: you@your.domain
Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------

\endpreamble
\postamble

Copyright (C) 2009 by You <you@your.domain>

This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
version.  The latest version of this license is in the file:

http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt

This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by
You.

This work consists of the file  democls.dtx
and the derived files           democls.ins,
                                democls.pdf and
                                democls.cls.

\endpostamble

\usedir{tex/latex/democls}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.cls}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{class}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/democls}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{doc/latex/democls}
\generate{
  \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*class>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%</class>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[numbered]{hypdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \def\fileversion{v1.0}
% \def\filedate{2009/10/06}
%
%\title{^^A
%  \textsf{democls} --- description text\thanks{^^A
%    This file describes version \fileversion, last revised \filedate.^^A
%  }^^A
%}
%\author{^^A
%  You\thanks{E-mail: you@your.domain}^^A
%}
%\date{Released \filedate}
%
%\maketitle
%
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{First public release}
%
%\DescribeMacro{\examplemacro}
% Some text about an example macro called \cs{examplemacro}, which

% might have an optional argument \oarg{arg1} and mandatory one
% \marg{arg2}.
%
%\StopEventually{^^A
%  \PrintChanges
%  \PrintIndex
%}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*class>
%    \end{macrocode}
%    
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ProvidesClass{democls}[2009/10/06 v1.0 description text]
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%\begin{macro}{\examplemacro}
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{Some change from the previous version}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*\examplemacro[2][]{%
  Some code here, probably
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</class>
%    \end{macrocode}
%\Finale
```

You can look to avoid duplicating the date/version strings, but in the main that will create as many issues as it solves. Thus I would be tempted to avoid it.

Comment: OK, this works, but I end with two distant date/version strings; Both need a warning comment: "Don't forget to adapt the other date/version if you change this one". Would it be possible to bring the two together within a few lines?

Comment: @WyboDekker Does [this](http://diffchecker.com/4cbx5ie0) fit your needs?

Comment: @JosephWright (Typing "@J" didn't display the completion) Does [this](http://diffchecker.com/4cbx5ie0) create as many issues as it solves?